# Laravel 4 missingMethod return a blank page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4 and I have a resource in my route as follows :

```
 Route::resource('admin/admins/actions', 'AdminActionsController');
```

My AdminActionsController.php controller has the missingMethod as follows:

```
    public function missingMethod($parameters = array())
{
 //show All Admin Users
return Redirect::to('admin/admins');
}
```

it suppose to redirect to admin/admins whenever there is a missing Method , but when I try something like admin/admins/actions/test  , I get a Blank Page? Anyone knows why?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an `index()` function?

Comment: does it redirect to show() function ? Do you have that implemented ?

Comment: also keep in mind, depending on your laravel version,add $method as the first parameter ( in laravel 4.0 )

Comment: did you fixed the error ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the error that a general Controller it gives you when it didn't found any function, you will see that it's the

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    throw new \BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist.");
}
```

and not `missingMethod` ( even though in documentation it says it does )

if you override the __call function like :

```
    public function __call($method,$parameters = array())
{
 //show All Admin Users
return Redirect::to('admin/admins');
}
```

It will work just as intended.

Keep in mind that for example, if you have the call, for example :

```
admin/admins/actions/foobar
```

It will not give you a missing function, because `foobar` is considered to be an $id, that is passed to the show($id) function . If you don't have the show function, only then it will give you that the function is missing.